# GPU Accelerators using Intel IPP Asynchronous Libraries

Tags: c++, intel, gpu

I am using the February Preview of IPP Asynchronous Libraries for C/C++. I have been working on a project which requires me to create a single accelerator from a file and use it over multiple files. CPU accelerator created in this manner is being used over the files without any problem and generating the expected results. However, even when I explicitly direct the program to create a GPU accelerator, it still creates a CPU accelerator and uses it for the computations.

The examples provided with the Feb release are successfully creating a GPU accelerator (HPP_ACCEL_TYPE_GPU_VIA_DX9) when directed, hence the system specifications and drivers are in place.

Is it because I am writing the code on one machine and using the generated dlls for running a program on another machine?

Both the machines have the IPP February release installed, but only one(destination machine) has the hardware specifications capable of GPU acceleration. I am writing the code on another(source) machine, building it, and transferring the dlls generated to the destination machine.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: The problem wasn't because of running the application on destination machine using dlls from source machine. Rather, it seems that .dll can't call for GPU acceleration which, for the same code though, an executable can do. Would appreciate if someone can suggest a workaround for this problem. Thanks